# Force input time 12/24-hour format

Tags: html, forms, cross-browser

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time) that the most common browsers will show the 12/24-hour format for the input time field according to the system settings.

Does that mean there is no way to force either of the two formats?

Comment: That's how browser widgets typically work, and one of the reasons why there're so many JavaScript libraries to reimplement them.